# Can't get Ubuntu 16.04 to boot after installing

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, system-installation, initramfs

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my old desktop. The first hard drive will hold Ubuntu, and a second hard drive holds Windows 10 on it currently. Booting into Windows 10 works fine if I select it from the BIOS.  I install Ubuntu with a Live USB created with Universal USB Installer 1.9.6.6. The live version of Ubuntu loads up and works fine. I install using the shortcut on the Live Ubuntu desktop and then I am unable to get a boot to the desktop environment. After throwing myself at it for hours today I am at wits end on trying to sort this.

Notes on the Process:

Boot LiveUSB

Install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS -- Shortcut

```
English 
Download Updates & Install 3rd part software
Erase Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and reinstall -- Install Now
    Pop Up Warning
        Partition tables of the following devices are changed: SCSI1(0,0,0)(sda)
        Following partitions are going to be formatted:
            partition #1 of SCSI1(0,0,0)(sda) as ext4
            partition #5 of SCSI1(0,0,0)(sda) as swap
        continue
Time Zone - NY
Keyboard Layout -English (US) - English(US)
Set User & Password - require password to log in -- continue
Install Process Begins
Install finishes - Restart Now
    Options for Setup (f2) and Boot Options (f12)
Burgundy blank Screen (NOT GRUB)
    Appears unresponsive, no blinking cursor
        tried (ctrl+alt+f1) (alt+f7) (f6) (alt+tab)
    Maintains Burgundy screen throughout
    ~5 minutes later, screen is still burgundy and unresponsive
    ~15 minutes no changes; force power off by holding down power button
Power On
    Options for Setup (f2) and Boot Options (f12)
GNU GRUB version 2.02^beta2-36ubuntu3.1
    Ubuntu
    Advanced options for Ubuntu
    Memory test (memtest86+)
    Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
Enter to boot into Ubuntu (top option)
black screen blinking cursor
    Unresponsive (after all while moves to next step)
Screen: Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems: 
 -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   -Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
 ALERT UUID=(numbers) does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
  Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
  Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
  (initramfs)_  (blinking cursor, but does not take any keyboard input)
Power Off by holding down power button
```

I've tried a few other things as well such as adding nomodeset to the launch options via grub, radeon.modeset=0, thinking of ways to brutally destroy the machine, running boot-repair through the live version.

Broke hyperlinks with spaces due to lacking reputation to post more than two links.

Images:

`initramfs` unresponsive:

[image]

`initramfs` unresponsive:

[image]

[http://i.imgur.com/5lhF0US.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/5lhF0US.jpg) (GRUB2)

Logs from two DIFFERENT boot-repairs:

https://paste2.org/YdHyFhM4

https://paste2.org/Zsxc2X66

Edit: [http://imgur.com/a/Mq33Y](https://imgur.com/a/Mq33Y) (link to album of images)

Comment: Please boot the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and get a screenshot of gparted view of your Ubuntu hard disk. Also, in terminal, type **sudo blkid**, and post both results here. And lastly, also in terminal, type **grep menuentry {mountpoint}/boot/grub/grub.cfg** (change {mountpoint} to the correct value) and post here. Cheers, Al

Comment: Your flash drive seems to get promoted to sda. And grub defaults install to sda, So if using any of the auto install options, grub overwrites your flash drive boot loader.  Then you have issues booting installer also. Use Something Else and install grub to MBR or whatever drive it is seen as like sdb.

Comment: GRUB (/boot/grub/grub.cfg) and/or /etc/fstab, or both, are looking for the wrong UUID. We may end up temporarily changing UUID to /dev/sda?. Cheers, Al

Comment: Installing from a Ubuntu Live DVD **ALWAYS** works better than installing from a USB flash drive. Maybe you'll need to try that to reinstall. Cheers, Al

Comment: FYI, your link to the screenshot for GRUB is broken but the other links work.

Comment: Heynnema, I have done as you requested. The results are contained within the images in the album below. Thank you for your help!

http://imgur.com/a/Mq33Y

Comment: Oldfred, currently in the Live version I can see the hard drive as sda, windows hard drive as sdb, and the usb as sdc in gparted (images below). So is it being promoted at some point during the install? I did have issues with the booting off the live version last night after installing. It would boot to the grub menu and then fail. 

Edwinksl, I think I fixed the GRUB image link, but it's also included in the added album. Thanks for pointing out that it broke.

Comment: Heynnema, would "/dev/sda" work as an address in place of the UUID? I would use a DVD if I could, but I no longer have an optical drive in that desktop. Thanks again.

Comment: I've taken a look at your screenshots. Thanks for posting those. The UUID's are wrong, however grub.cfg looks right. Have you been trying to boot Ubuntu while the USB flash drive is inserted? Try two things. 1) remove the flash drive, cold boot the computer, hopefully either GRUB or Windows Boot Manager shows up. Choose Ubuntu. 2) at cold boot, bring up the BIOS boot menu, probably by hitting F12 key (may vary by manufacturer), then choose sda or whichever entry might be your Ubuntu hard disk. See what happens. Report back. Cheers, Al

Comment: FYI: When directing a comment to a specific person, place an "@" in front of the username, like @heynnema. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema, I have tried booting with and without the flash drive inserted. 
Shut down from live version. Removed USB
 Powered On.
 Grub 2 screen appears. 
 Enter on Ubuntu.
 Black screen with blinking cursor.
  Appears to be Unresponsive.
  Screen with Gave up waiting for root device...
  (initramfs)_ blinking cursor, unresponsive to keyboard input. 
 Hard Power Off.

Same results when selecting the hard drive through BIOS.

Comment: You just need to reinstall Ubuntu when booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD. I'd disconnect the Windows hard drive just to make sure it doesn't get touched. Once you get a bootable Ubuntu system, you can always reattach the Windows drive and **sudo update-grub** to be able to boot either Ubuntu or Windows from GRUB. Sorry, but I don't have any better ideas than that. Let me know how you make out. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema, Dragged an optical drive out of an even older desktop and booted using the Live DVD. It's boots off the hard drive now.

Is there a way to mark this as solved now??

Comment: added as an answer. you can vote/accept it if you like. A Ubuntu reinstall solved the problem, yes? And can you boot both Ubuntu and Windows from GRUB? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

After a lengthy discussion and troubleshooting in the comments, it was decided that a Ubuntu reinstall from DVD would solve the problem. Cheers, Al